# How to force XmlSerializer to include an empty tag for empty list

Tags: c#, .net, xml

For whatever reason, empty lists are not included by the XmlSerializer during serialization. I've not found much documentation on whether this behavior is correct or whether it can be overridden.  I'm including the code for the type I'm trying to serialize and the serialization code in the hopes someone can shed some light on this.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/FacilitySettings.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/FacilitySettings.xsd", IsNullable=true)]
public class WeightSettings
{

          public List<string> WeightOZIdentifiers 
          {
                get 
                {
                    return this.weightOZIdentifiersField;
                }
                set 
                {
                    this.weightOZIdentifiersField = value;
                }
           }
}


public static string ToXmlString<T>(this T obj)
{
     var builder = new StringBuilder();
     using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder))
     {
         var xml = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
         var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
         serializer.Serialize(xml, obj);
         return builder.ToString();
     }
}
```

edited to reflect

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlSerializer` cannot serialize an empty array because he doesn't know the size of this array.
try initialize the array first and then serialize it.

```
WeightOZIdentifiers = new string[10];
```

Comment: Jacob,  my object model actually uses Lists not arrays.  Edited question to reflect this.